# View don't fit the screen after rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, autorotate

while in the simulator the problem don't subsist, i've a problem with a view after auto rotating to landscape orientation. When I load the app in portrait, all works fine, but when i rotate the device (iPod touch 1st gen. 3.1.3) to landscape the result is this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/155/img0021n.png/ .
If i switch to the second view ("Riepilogo" i.e. a table view) and then back to the first, the view fit perfectly in landscape, but if I rotate again to the portrait orientation, the problem is the same as above.

Here is the code of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

    [self.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(480,416)]; 

} else {

    [self.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 416)];

}

return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); }
```

**P.S. The view is an instance of  UIScrollView**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing a scrollview doesn't resize its contents.

Comment: A scrollview has subviews.  Resize the ones you want to resize.